# Spring SAML and ADFS 2.0

Tags: spring, saml, adfs2.0, adfs3.0

I used Spring SAML Sample application and followed the instructions. My configuration worked perfectly as expected, when SSOCircle IDP was used. However, I wanted to work this with ADFS. So, I followed the instructions on how to configure Spring SAML with ADFS. I got it through where when I access Spring SAML application is invoked, it displays the IDP Selection page with URL to adfs/services/trust. When I click on it, it prompts me for AD authentication, which is what I expected. But, when I provide the user id/password for the AD authentication, it process it and displays a message that reads "page can't be displayed".

On the address bar, the url to the page is displayed as:

https://localhost:8443/spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/login?idp=http%3A%2F%2FTest-DC.TEST.local%2Fadfs%2Fservices%2Ftrust.

Test-DC.TEST.local is my server where ADFS and AD is hosted.

There are no errors on the tomcat log or anywhere.

could someone who has setup Spring SAML with ADFS help here please?

Comment: You may use a SAML tracer first to obtain the assertion. Based on the Binding used there may be an issue with XML signature.
Without the error message from the logs it's hard to tell, even for someone who set it up successfully with ADFS. The Spring SAML docs also have section from ADFS integration.

Comment: thanks. I will try using SAML tracer. FYI: I used ADFS integration from Spring Docs

Comment: Look in the ADFS event log and see what the errors are.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're using SHA2 and not SHA1.

either override the afterPropertiesSet method:

```
    public class SSOConfigBean 
  implements InitializingBean 
{

  private String signatureAlgorithmSHA = SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA256;
  private String digestAlgorithmSHA = SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA256;

  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception 
  {
    BasicSecurityConfiguration config = (BasicSecurityConfiguration) Configuration.getGlobalSecurityConfiguration();
    config.registerSignatureAlgorithmURI("RSA", signatureAlgorithmSHA);
    config.setSignatureReferenceDigestMethod(digestAlgorithmSHA);
  }
}
```

and add this to your securityContext:

```
  <!-- setting encryption to SHA2 instead of default SHA1 -->
  <bean class="path.to.SSOConfigBean"/>
```

Or update the securityContext you're using while setting your SP metadata as below:

```
  <bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
      <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
        <property name="entityId" value="urn:samltest"/>
        <property name="extendedMetadata">
          <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
            <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false"/>
            <property name="local" value="true"/>
            <property name="signingAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
          </bean>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>
```